# ORACLE 18c in CentOs 7 "Unable to check for available memory"

Tags: oracle

I download and upload to server:

1// **oracle-database-preinstall-18c-1.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm**

2// **oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm**

after I run

```
yum -y localinstall oracle-database-preinstall-18c-1.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

all fine, no problem; after I run:

```
rpm -i oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm
```

all fine, no problem with result:

```
[root@server 000]# rpm -i oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm
warning: oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID ec551f03: NOKEY
[INFO] Executing post installation scripts...
[INFO] Oracle home installed successfully and ready to be configured.
To configure Oracle Database XE, optionally modify the parameters in '/etc/sysconfig/oracle-xe-18c.conf' and then execute '/etc/init.d/oracle-xe-18c configure' as root.
[root@server 000]#
```

then I go to "run last line", but when I run

```
/etc/init.d/oracle-xe-18c configure
```

in server with **4 GB RAM** result is:

```
Unable to check for available memory
```

then I go to other server with 8GB in memory, and when I run:

```
/etc/init.d/oracle-xe-18c configure
```

in server with **8 GB RAM** result is:

```
Unable to check for available memory
```

in both servers message is:

```
Unable to check for available memory
```

in both servers:

```
[root@server 000]# cat /etc/system-release;
CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)
[root@server 000]#
```

also I change from default [false] to [true]:

```
SKIP_VALIDATIONS=true
```

in **/etc/sysconfig/oracle-xe-18c.conf**

what I can do to resolve this issue?

this is dedicated server, no VPS

Thanks by your help

Comment: Perhaps these are related https://community.oracle.com/thread/4194129 and https://easyoradba.com/2018/08/12/oracle-18c-18-3-dbca-issue-dbt-50000-dbt-50001/

Comment: jspcal I am confused I get `-bash: dbca: command not found` **when I run** `dbca -createDatabase -silent -gdbName ora18c -templateName General_Purpose.dbc -sysPassword sys123 -systemPassword sys123 -dbsnmpPassword sys123 -datafileDestination /u01/oradata -storageType FS -memoryPercentage 20 -emConfiguration NONE -sampleSchema false -J-Doracle.assistants.dbca.validate.ConfigurationParams=false` **I get** `[root@server ~]# -bash: dbca: command not found[root@server ~]#`

Answer (score 0):

"**Unable to check for available memory**"

I fixed in this form:

I go to my other server with OLD installation Oracle (running fine Oracle 11g), then I find 3 files:

```
oracle_env.csh    
oracle_env.sh    
nls_lang.sh
```

becouse this files **no exist** in new server, I create and put into folder Oracle:

```
/opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/bin
```

with the content (**path correct**) into the files

1. oracle_env.csh
2. oracle_env.sh

and put this lines into they:

```
touch /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/bin/oracle_env.csh
echo 'setenv ORACLE_HOME /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE
setenv ORACLE_SID XE
setenv NLS_LANG `$ORACLE_HOME/bin/nls_lang.sh`
setenv PATH $ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH' >> /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/bin/oracle_env.csh
```

after second file:

```
touch /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/bin/oracle_env.sh
echo 'export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE
export ORACLE_SID=XE
export NLS_LANG=`$ORACLE_HOME/bin/nls_lang.sh`
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH' >> /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/bin/oracle_env.sh
```

becouse the file **nls_lang.sh** is very long and have many config about CHARSET, I copy from OLD server to NEW server.

after is necesary config owner/group of this files:

```
chown oracle:oinstall /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/bin/oracle_env.csh
chown oracle:oinstall /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/bin/oracle_env.sh
chown oracle:oinstall /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/bin/nls_lang.sh
```

also the file **nls_lang.sh** require 755:

```
chmod 0755 /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/bin/nls_lang.sh
```

is necesary login as user oracle:

```
su -l oracle
```

then I go to folder and load vars environment:

```
cd /opt/oracle/product/18c/dbhomeXE/bin
. ./oracle_env.sh
```

finally I can run the command **dbca**:

```
dbca -createDatabase -silent -gdbName ora18c -templateName XE_Database.dbc -sysPassword YourPWD1 -systemPassword YourPWD1 -dbsnmpPassword YourPWD1 -datafileDestination /opt/oracle/oradata -storageType FS -memoryPercentage 20 -emConfiguration NONE -sampleSchema false -J-Doracle.assistants.dbca.validate.ConfigurationParams=false
```

and I get the greath result:

```
[server@petro bin]$ dbca -createDatabase -silent -gdbName ora18c -templateName XE_Database.dbc -sysPassword YourPWD1 -systemPassword YourPWD1 -dbsnmpPassword YourPWD1 -datafileDestination /opt/oracle/oradata -storageType FS -memoryPercentage 20 -emConfiguration NONE -sampleSchema false -J-Doracle.assistants.dbca.validate.ConfigurationParams=false
Prepare for db operation
10% complete
Copying database files
40% complete
Creating and starting Oracle instance
42% complete
46% complete
50% complete
54% complete
60% complete
Completing Database Creation
66% complete
69% complete
70% complete
Executing Post Configuration Actions
100% complete
Database creation complete. For details check the logfiles at:
/opt/oracle/cfgtoollogs/dbca/ora18c.
Database Information:
Global Database Name:ora18c
System Identifier(SID):ora18c
Look at the log file "/opt/oracle/cfgtoollogs/dbca/ora18c/ora18c.log" for further details.
[server@petro bin]$
```

becouse I need PHP in this servers, I require OCI8, then I run:

```
/usr/bin/ea-php72-pecl install oci8
/usr/bin/ea-php71-pecl install oci8
/usr/bin/ea-php70-pecl install oci8
```

when this request:

```
**Please provide the path to the ORACLE_HOME directory. Use 'instantclient,/path/to/instant/client/lib' if you're compiling with Oracle Instant Client [autodetect] :**
```

simply [ENTER] then this run fine for me...

Regards.

Comment: Oracle 18c XE now uses the same configuration files `/usr/local/bin/oraenv` and `/usr/local/bin/coraenv` that are used by Enterprise Edition.  That is why `oracle_env.* ` are no longer included.